# NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, pry

I'm in pry and this image is giving me some troubles in Nokogiri. E.g.

```
[8] pry(main)> img
=> #(Element:0x3fe805871b94 {
name = "img",
attributes = [
#(Attr:0x3fe8058716d0 { name = "alt", value = "Alt text here" }),
#(Attr:0x3fe805870460 { name = "src", value = "/path/to/file/a.jpg" }),
#(Attr:0x3fe80587044c { name = "style", value = "width: 452px; height: 190px" })]
})
[9] pry(main)> URI.escape(img)
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007fd00b0e3728>
from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:304:in `escape'
```

Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: The error is very clear as to why. The question is why did you think this would work and what are you expecting to happen. Please answer these questions in the post and then people will be more likely to help.

Comment: Your question is puzzling. If you're using Nokogiri, it's a pretty reasonable for us to assume you're fairly aware of how objects and their methods work. That you got `inspect` output for a Nokogiri::XML::Element should be a hint that you're not dealing with a String, which is what `URI.escape` expects. So, Ruby complaining that `gsub` isn't valid for a non-String parameter seems sensible.

Comment: When I looked at the docs for URI.escape it all became clear. I was assuming that URI.escape would take the Nokogiri XML Element, pull out just the URI and escape it to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't escape a Nokogiri XML Element, it's a complicated Ruby object that the URI escaper has no idea how to use. You could escape a particular attribute on it that's a string.

For example:

```
URI.escape(img.attr('src'))
```